# Duplicated feature and criteria from sklearn RandomForest when examining the decision path

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I'm getting duplicated feature and threshold (CO2) when examining the decision tree from a random forest model. The code to visualize the tree is the following:

```
estimator = model.estimators_[10]
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
# Export as dot file
export_graphviz(estimator, out_file='tree.dot', 
                feature_names = ['pdo', 'pna', 'lat', 'lon', 'ele', 'co2'],
                class_names = 'disWY',
                rounded = False, proportion = False, 
                precision = 3, filled = True)

# Convert to png using system command (requires Graphviz)
from subprocess import call
call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'tree.dot', '-o', 'tree.png', '-Gdpi=300'])

# Display in jupyter notebook
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename = 'tree.png')
```

It is clear that CO2 and -0.69 are used twice. I don't understand how this is possible. Anyone has any idea?

[screen shot of decision tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSrQl.png)

Should it be different threshold for the same feature?

Comment: My guess they differ in some decimals behind it and these are rounded values.

Comment: @Daraan Yes that's my first guess. But I've changed ```rounded``` to false, and also you can see ```PDO``` and ```lat``` are both three decimals, while ```co2``` is always two decimals.

Comment: I think there's a slight misunderstanding: the [`rounded`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html) parameter represents whether to "draw node boxes with rounded corners." `precision` controls the number of decimal points. Maybe try `precision=8`? And perhaps plot a histogram of `co2` values, the distribution may be odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a rounding error.

It's a little contrived, but here's a minimal way to reproduce this with `RandomForestRegressor`

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

X = np.array([[-0.6901, 4.123],
              [-0.6902, 5.456],
              [-0.6903, 6.789],
              [-0.6904, 7.012]])
y = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0])

reg = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42).fit(X, y)

export_graphviz(reg.estimators_[6], out_file=f"tree6.dot", precision=3, filled=True)
# dot -Tpng tree6.dot -o tree6.png
```

[image: Decision tree, showing that feature 0 is split on twice when the value is less than or equal to -0.69]

If instead we passed a higher `precision=8` when calling `export_graphviz()` we would see something like this:

[image: The same tree with higher precision in floating point numbers. With higher precision, it appears that the error was caused by limited precision when exporting a graphviz representation.]